# Is it possible to use Vertex Array Objects on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: opengl-es, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, vertex-array-object

Is it possible to use [Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) on Raspberry Pi?
Can I load it as extension?

Comment: What do `eglinfo` & `glxinfo` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the the eginfo [here](https://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_VideoCore_APIs#OpenGL_ES):

> The Raspberry Pi supports OpenGL ES 2.0 with the following extensions:
>
> GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
>   GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_vertex_half_float
>   GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
>   GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_mapbuffer
>   GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_EXT_debug_marker

"Nominal" OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't support Vertex Array Objects. The extension that provides support for it is [OES_vertex_array_object](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_vertex_array_object.txt), which isn't in this list. So, no, you can't use them on Raspberry Pi.